# Why is TAM Airlines baggage allowance so much?

Tags: air-travel, luggage, brazil

I travel around Europe, and also between Australia and Europe quite a bit and am always frustrated with the low luggage allowance (just 23kg per person normally).

I do also travel to Brazil quite a bit and TAM Airlines have a baggage allowance of 2 x 32kg each (64kg!!).

Why do they offer such a large baggage allowance when so many other airlines can't?

It seems they also offer it only from London and Frankfurt to Brazil - why is this?

My fiance is Brazilian - and believe me when I say - needs the 64kg for all the clothes and shoes we normally take over there.  I'm just wondering why it seems to be just TAM offering this.

Comment: Brazilians must be deathly afraid of cold European weather.

Comment: What on earth are you carrying that you are frustrated with 23kg? I just moved to Vancouver with two laptops, 3 months of medication, an SLR, 3 pairs of shoes and all my clothing (plus a book), and was still only 19kg (plus 7kg carry-on). :/  I don't think I could physically carry 64kg...

Comment: @MarkMayo Get married and all your questions about lack of baggage carrying capacity will be answered. :)

Comment: Haha, fair point, although I know many married couples who still manage just fine with 23kg.  One couple went from London to South America and NZ for several months, with two carry-on packs only!  I just query how on earth you even carry 128kg (2x32 bags, for two people) - plus carry-on.  Especially if you're a backpack user; I would not want that on my back!

Comment: Brazil's laws are very pro-consumer, which means that you end up with high baggage allowance without having to pay for it.

Comment: @MarkMayo Going to Brazil tonight - and guess what, we've got 2 x about 25 - 30kg each.  Not only our stuff but requested items from Brazilian family :)

Comment: @arboc7 Then why can they only offer this from London and Frankfurt?

Comment: Perhaps that is their [USP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_selling_proposition)? To me, this sounds like an unanswerable question.

Comment: Hi David, after considering this for a while and consulting with @MarkMayo, this seems to be a question that cannot be answered objectively. "Q. How can an airline afford to give so much luggage allowance for free?! A. Because they can!"

Comment: or "because they want to", or "because they have no sense" - without actually consulting them we won't know the reason, aside from assuming it's their USP (See above)

Comment: Despite all the jokes, I think this is an interesting question. The baggage allowance on flights to Brazil on most (all?) airlines (not just TAM) is more generous than for other regions. In fact, if you read baggage allowance rules (example here http://www.delta.com/traveling_checkin/baggage/checked/index.jsp) you'll see there is almost always a special case for Brazil. I've heard that this is due to international treaties, but I'd be interested to hear the complete details.

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/17914/why-is-the-baggage-allowance-on-flights-to-from-brazil-more-generous