# Why is the baggage allowance on flights to/from Brazil more generous?

Tags: air-travel, luggage, factoids, brazil

It seems that it is common that the baggage allowance on flights to Brazil is more generous (both in number of pieces and weight) than to other countries. In fact many airlines, have a specific exception to their general rules for Brazil. Examples:

- [Delta](http://www.delta.com/content/www/en_US/traveling-with-us/baggage/before-your-trip/checked.html)
- [American Airlines](https://www.aa.com/i18n/travelInformation/baggage/baggageAllowance.jsp)
- [TAP](http://book.flytap.com/bagsim/BaggageStart.aspx)
- [United](http://www.united.com/CMS/en-US/travel/Pages/CheckedBaggage.aspx)

I've heard a rumor, that this may be related to international treaties, but I'm not sure. Does anyone know the answer?

Related question: [Why is TAM Airlines baggage allowance so much? [closed]](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/7165/why-is-tam-airlines-baggage-allowance-so-much?rq=1)

Comment: Several Google hits agree that this allowance is a requirement of the Brazilian government, either by treaty or unilaterally.  In principle you could probably find it in Brazil's equivalent of the Federal Register; I didn't try since I can't read Portuguese.

Comment: US Airways has the same policy also -- I noticed it on a sign at the airport when checking in for a flight last week. First two bags free if going to Brazil, and much less charged for additional bags. Same policy for transpacific flights (except high charger for 3rd and 4th bags).  For transatlantic and rest of North/South America/Caribbean they charge for 1st bag on up.

Comment: Not only Brazil, Argentina, Canada, and the U.S. also got the same advantage.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Evidently it's a [ANAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Civil_Aviation_Agency_of_Brazil) (National Civil Aviation Agency of Brazil) regulation.  From [KLM's website](http://www.klm.com/travel/br_en/prepare_for_travel/baggage/excess/exbag_BR.htm):

> For tickets whose itinerary originates in Brazil (for both the
>   outbound and inbound journeys),  the Civil Aviation Authority Agency
>   (ANAC) determines that for each adult passenger, the free bagagge
>   allowance consists of 2 pieces* of max. weight of 32kgs (70 lbs) each.
>   The sum of the 3 dimensions of each piece cannot exceed 158 cm (62
>   in.) and the sum of the dimentions of both pieces cannot exceed 273 cm
>   (107 in.).

As to why this is, there's speculation that it allows more people to shop both in Brazil and overseas and bring stuff back to Brazil / take it from Brazil - meaning more tax can be charged on these items.  But that's just speculation.

Comment: For those that can read Portuguese, ANAC's travel tips pamphlet has the rules: http://www2.anac.gov.br/dicasanac/pdf/novo/anac_panfleto_bagagem.pdf  Summary: 2x32kg on the "piece system" or 20kg total in economy class on the "weight system". New rules are being proposed that are supposed to clarify the old rules, but the look pretty similar: http://www.anac.gov.br/noticia.aspx?ttcd_chave=934

Comment: I suppose the additional tax that could be raised on luggage might be an incentive, but after living in Brazil for three years, I think it has more to do with the Brazilian government meddling in anything it can especially when it involves giving people (or consumers) "rights". I mean they have enshrined in their _constitution_ that female prisoners with children must be allowed to breast feed their babies!

Comment: Yeah I did wonder about whether it was a civil liberties type of thing, but couldn't find anything to back that theory up. Thanks for the links!

Answer (score 6):

The worldwide luggage limit was 70 pounds or 32 kilos for decades.
Airlines smelled blood in the water and figured out how to squeeze every last drop of revenue from their passengers by restricting and charging for accompanied luggage.

Brazil gave the airlines a hearty middle finger and kept the rules the same as they have always been.

If any airlines don't like it or don't want to respect the rule, they're not welcome to fly to Brazil.  Very Simple.

For ONCE Brazil was right and the rest of the world was wrong.  ;-)

Comment: Luggage restrictions are often about limiting the amount of weight luggage handlers need to pick up, not just "corporate greed".

Answer (score 4):

True  until recently, in late 2017 / early 2018  airlines now have implemented  new baggage allowances for Brazil, down from 70 pounds (32Kg) to 50 Pounds (23Kg). Check each airline for number of bags per type of ticket.