# Air China number of bags Spain to Brazil

Tags: air-travel, luggage, air-china

I'm flying economy class from MAD to GRU but the e-ticket is ambiguous when it comes to this combination of origin and destination (I've highlighted the part that I consider relevant):

[image]

In ii) B) should I consider that it only refers to routes involving Mainland China?

Comment: Your case seems to fall under (ii) (B). You're going from a third country (Spain), to the Americas, transiting in Mainland China.

Comment: That Air China MAD-GRU flight is not transiting in Mainland China, is a direct flight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MAD-GRU is a [fifth-freedom flight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freedoms_of_the_air) (a sixth-freedom flight is a form of fifth-freedom) that appears to fall under ii) B. and thus allows you a two piece allowance. The full route would be PEK-MAD-GRU

The wording is somewhat ambiguous, however I believe all flights to and from Brazil require that two pieces of check-in luggage are allowed. See: [Why is the baggage allowance on flights to/from Brazil more generous?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/17914/why-is-the-baggage-allowance-on-flights-to-from-brazil-more-generous)

A dummy booking for MAD-GRU on airchina.us and airchina.uk also shows 2 pieces:

[image]

Comment: Fifth and sixth freedoms are quite different. Fifth means (in the case of Air China) China-country 1-country 2, which is the case here. Sixth freedom means country 1-China-country 2, which is not the case here. ii) B is quite explicit about it: flight from other country to Americas via China, which is not the case.

Comment: Also the exception for Brazil described in that question seems to apply to flight originating in Brazil. Not sure if that’s je case of the OP.

Comment: Still find the wording ambiguous on my e-ticket, but after flying I can confirm they let me check-in 2 bags for free

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are only entitled to one piece of luggage.

ii) B is quite explicit about it: flight from a country other than China to Americas **via China** (defined as a sixth freedom flight), which is not the case here, you are flying from one country other than China to another country other than China (a fifth freedom flight).

Not sure if Air China do this, but many airlines make your actual allowance quite explicit on their “manage my booking” pages (usually with an option to buy more), so I would recommend you check that.